# Turning an Array into a string PHP Object

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am trying to convert an array from a result in my method but it's not working for me.

I a trying to get the First and Last name of the user I am messaging. I used `var_dump` and `print_r` to see if there is a value there and it shows me everything in the users row(Even though I don't want it). The way am I trying works for my comments but it's not working here. I tried implode(). The current code I have shows the word Array and the First and Last name. Can someone show me what's wrong ?

```
public function getFirstAndLastName() {

$query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$query->bind_param("s", $this->user['username']);
$query->execute();
$query_result = $query->get_result();

/*if ($query_result != FALSE) {

    return true;
} else {

    return false;
} */

return $query_result->fetch_assoc() ?? ['first_name' => '[no', 'last_name' => 'name]'];
}
```

---

```
echo "<h4>You and <a href='" . $username ."'>" .
$userResult = $profile_user_obj->getFirstAndLastName(); 
  echo $userResult['first_name'] . " " . $userResult['last_name'];
"</a></h4><hr><br>";

 echo "<div class='loaded_messages' id='scroll_messages'>";
 echo $message_obj->getMessages($username) . '</div>';
```

This is how it works in my comments code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $posted_by; ?>" target="_parent">
<b> <?php $userResult = $user_obj->getFirstAndLastName();
echo $userResult['first_name'] . " " . $userResult['last_name'];?></b></a>  
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php echo $time_message . "&nbsp;" . '' 
.  "<br>" . $post_body; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by a typo with concatenating the anchor tag with the `$userResult` variable.

eg: `echo <a> . $userResult = profile_user_obj->getFirstAndLastName() . '</a>'`

To resolve the issue, move `$userResult` above your initial `echo`.
You also need to fix the concatenation with the closing anchor `</a>`

```
$userResult = $profile_user_obj->getFirstAndLastName(); 
echo "<h4>You and <a href='" . $username ."'>" .
$userResult['first_name'] . " " . $userResult['last_name'] .
"</a></h4><hr><br>";
```